# Do rel canonical tags permanently affect link juice, or can they be undone later?

Tags: seo, canonical-url, link-juice

Does placing the `rel=canonical` tag pass the link juice to the canonicalised page forever? What I'm trying to say is, if one were to canonicalise page b to page a, would then reverting that change (for turning it into its own page lets say) leave some link juice and hence ranking "power" behind on page a or would b simply retain all that it had transferred via the canonicalisation signal it had sent to Google?

Answer (score 1):

If

- page a is no longer marked by you as the canonical version of page b
- and Google rescans both
- and page a and page b have significantly different content

then Google may decide that they should not consider page a as canonical version of page b any more. It is safe to assume that within a few million seconds, link juice and ranking power will sort out as if the canonical tag had never been there.

Comment: thanks, though as far as I know google scans more popular content more frequent, so given my content being for a hot keyword, would it be safe to assume that it'd take less than say month?

Comment: I would also like to share link to a the article that made me suspect this: https://moz.com/blog/can-you-reverse-a-301-redirect  . The thing is, 301 being a strong canonicalisation signal combined with the fact that 301's will hurt ranking if taken back made me question this. Could you comment on this specific matter if you could? (My argument was that reverting a "permanent" redirect was googles way of penalizing gaming the system)