# Can PageRank be returned to a relisted page that was previously delisted via 301 redirect?

Tags: seo, 301-redirect, pagerank

If an old page on website A is replaced with a 301 redirect to another website such that the page on website A is delisted from Google (as desired) but the website owner decides afterwards that they actually prefer to keep the page on website A ranked, if they remove the 301 redirect and restore the old page on website A, does that page regain the PageRank it had before?

In other words, can the process be reversed without loss of PageRank? Does Google keep historical records of PageRank that can be re-activated when a page is re-listed?

Comment: A few days ago we got a similar question about canonical tags:  [Do rel canonical tags permanently affect link juice, or can they be undone later?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/133204/do-rel-canonical-tags-permanently-affect-link-juice-or-can-they-be-undone-later)

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Thanks. I'm interested in the answer to that question, too, although it doesn't fit my scenario and the answer to both could differ. The link posted in a comment there looks like it answers my question (https://moz.com/blog/can-you-reverse-a-301-redirect) but I have found some articles on Moz.com to be outdated. If there is a more authoritative source (like Google) it would be even better. If not, that one could suffice as an answer. If you'd like to post an answer based on that link, feel free.